# How to select same jquery element after page refresh? Like if i have element $("td.treeItem"),

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select same jquery element after page refresh? Like if i have element $("td.treeItem"), after page refresh i want to select same element using same jquery object?

Comment: I want to highlight that element after some actions done using coding.

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no state maintaned in **Javascript** after a page refresh. However, even though I do not recommend this, you could store your element selector (in this case `td.treeItem`) inside `localstorage`, which is a data storage inside the browser that keeps track of stored elements for the same domain (i.e you have a "localStorage" for each domain).

To achieve what you want you simply need to do this:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value) //In your case key can be treeItem and value td.treeItem, for example.
```

Then, upon reloading your page you should add a listener on document ready and retrieve this item from the localStorage. This is done as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var treeItem = localStorage.getItem(key) //In your case treeItem or whatever key you chose
  //perform desired operation over treeItem
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is stateless protocol.we cant maintain a state between multiple page requests.if you want to main state between multiple request means ,you need to go for HTML5 web storage